# Diisplay advanced custom field data on woocommerce my account page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a metbox with advanced custom fields for the woocommerce admin edit order page. Now I want to display that metadata in my account. But not being displayed. Where is the problem?

```
function add_account_orders_column_rows2 ( $order ) {
if ( $value = $order->get_field( 'custom_price' ) ) {
    echo esc_html( $value );   
}
```

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_price_colums', 'add_account_orders_column_rows2' );

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_meta()` try below code.

```
function add_account_orders_column_rows2 ( $order ) {
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        echo $item->get_meta('custom_price');
    }
} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_price_colums', 'add_account_orders_column_rows2' );
```

Comment: Text fields can be called this way.
01. But post object or relation field cannot be called.
02. Displays post object only shows post ID. But the title of the post does not show.